# How is $PATH used outside of the shell?

Tags: unix, path, cmake, linker

I was recently asked why a particular library (Accelerate) is not included in the $PATH variable in our Mac environment. My response to that is that $PATH is a shell concept, not an OS concept. I don't expect libraries to be included in $PATH since they aren't executable and aren't necessarily relevant in a shell.

However, is this true? Some googling says yes, but in that case how do tools like CMake automatically find libraries with `find_package` and `find_lapack`? Is there some system specific PATH variable or another similar concept?

Comment: AFAIK, Windows does look for DLLs in directories on `%PATH%`.  Unix systems tend to look for libraries in path-like variables with names such as `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (Mac OS X; macOS, sort of, with caveats), `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (Linux, Solaris), `SHLIB_PATH` (older HP-UX, newer versions also use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, IIRC), and `LIBPATH` (archaic AIX; current versions use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` too).  Some systems have `LD_RUN_PATH` for where to load libraries at run time, using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to guide the linker (and as a fallback).  No doubt I've missed some details.

Comment: *$PATH is a shell concept, not an OS concept* is not true. PATH is an environment variable required in `exec` function family. The way it is manipulated in shells is not defined, but this variable must be in the environment of every process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `PATH` environment variable is for storing paths to executable files. There is to my knowledge (nor did an internet search reveal one) no standard `PATH` equivalent for library locations.

Tools like `CMake` will typically search the standard locations. For a Unix flavored OS, these often include `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib` etc. See for example how `CMake` defines them: [UnixPaths.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Platform/UnixPaths.cmake).

[find_library()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/find_library.html) will search these standard locations (unless you tell it not to), and/or any path(s) given by the user.

[find_package()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/find_package.html) will search for a `Config` or `Find`-module, which is responsible for finding all the necessary package components (binaries, include folders etc) and make the package ready for use within CMake. As these are written for a specific package, they will typically employ some qualified "guess work" as to where to find the package and its components (search standard locations, typical install locations and/or any other arbitrary method to accomplish its mission). So it's not `CMake` itself that finds the package in this case.